# Python List Comprehension: Affix strings from one list to the start of strings in another, for a list of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists and I want to use a list comprehension to create a list of lists. The first list has some prefixes and the second has some suffixes.

```
prefixes = ['t1_', 't0_']
suffixes = ['price', 'sales']
```

The list comprehension should return

```
output = [['t1_price', 't1_sales'],
          ['t0_price', 't0_sales']]
```

I am able to accomplish this with a pair of for loops:

```
output = []
for prefix in prefixes:
    pairs = []
    for suffix in suffixes:
        pairs.append(prefix + suffix)
    output.append(pairs)
```

But I think a list comprehension would improve my code's readability.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also achieve this using list comprehension

```
[[p+s for s in suffixes] for p in prefixes]
#[['t1_price', 't1_sales'], ['t0_price', 't0_sales']]
```

Comment: Seems I misread the question (I didn't downvote your answer either). This is the right answer.

Comment: Thanks so much! (And thanks for your effort too, @COLDSPEED)

Comment: By the way, if you opt for the functional style, you can do the same using `list(map(lambda p: list(map(''.join, itertools.product([p], suffixes))), prefixes))`

Answer (score 0):

an alternative using a generator that does not require a nested comprehension

```
from itertools import product
[a+b for (a, b) in product(prefixes, suffixes)]
```

Answer (score -1):

output = [[x+y for x in prefixes] for y in suffixes]
print(output)